# How to group array based on multiple keys conditionally?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple issue grouping conditionally.

```
const aInput = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];
```

I want to group the array by day & code BUT if there is both A & B for one day then only B stays

```js
const aInput = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];


// I want to group the array above by day & code BUT if there is both A & B then only B stays


const aOutput = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}]
```

Comment: so you want to reduce the list first, remove duplicates etc. where is the code you've tried?

Comment: Check out this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

Create an accumulator with each `date` as key. If the accumulator doesn't have the current date in context or if the current object has the preferred code, then add the object as value.

(Added an additional `A` code object to demonstrate)

```js
const aInput = [
 {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
 {"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
 {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
 {"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
 {"date":"2018/9/12", "code":"A"}]

const preferredCode = "B";

const merged = aInput.reduce((r,{date, code}) =>{
  if(!r[date] || code === preferredCode)
      r[date] = {date, code};

  return r;
},{})

const final = Object.values(merged)

console.log(final)
```

The above code assumes that there are only 2 `code`s. If you have more than 2 `code`s and you want to get all the unique codes per day unless there is a `B`, then you can do the following using `reduce` and `some`

```js
const aInput = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/12", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/12", "code":"C"}]

const preferredCode = "B";

const merged = aInput.reduce((r,{date, code}) =>{
  r[date] =  r[date] || [];
  
  if(code === preferredCode)
    r[date] = [{date, code}]
  else if(!r[date].some(e => e.code === preferredCode || e.code === code))
    r[date].push({date, code})
   
  return r;
},{})

const final = [].concat.apply([],Object.values(merged))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by code in this array by using `.reduce`

```js
const aInput = [
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"A"},
{"date":"2018/9/10", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"},
{"date":"2018/9/11", "code":"B"}];

const result = aInput.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.code] = [...r[a.code] || [], a];
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```